# Shows an error if the pointer variable being displayed is changed

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

**I am a high school student currently learning C++.So while doing pointers I came across a problem,**

[image: first pointer programme]

**When I try to display the value at y,it shows**:[image: Terminal window]

**The value of x is displayed properly,but after I write *y as  *(x+1),it works fine**

[image]

**Can any one please explain why I am getting a segmentation fault?**

*Despite the what the screenshots show,all the code compiled perfectly.*

Comment: Please change the pictures to actual text. **And there is no need to type everything in bold.**

Answer (score 2):

`y` points to unallocated memory, so dereferencing it is undefined behaviour. You need point it at some valid memory, either by allocating it dynamically, or taking the address of a valid variable, like you did with `x`.

Answer (score 1):

You set `y` to `x+1`. **`x+1` does not point to an object.**

You then try to write data through `y`. **That's not going to work.**

It's not at all clear what you are trying to accomplish with this code, so I cannot suggest a remedy.